# Different UI For iPad and iPhone (Swift 3)

Tags: swift3

### **Different UI for iPhone and iPad**

I have a project requirement in which i need to make different UI for iPad and iPhone . I am confused how to do this .

1. Should i be taking different storyboards for each or use same
   storyboard .
2. If i choose to have same storyboard for both how should i manage the
   views, as Both have different UI but same code class has to be used
   .

   I am plannig to use different stroryboard for ipad and iPhone this way i will be able to use same classes , and different UI can easily be managed .
   Will this be the right approach?

Comment: Use size classes if it is just a matter of layout.

Comment: UI for Ipad and iphone will be totally different . Do you still recommend that i should be using the same storyboard for both ? Wont it be difficult to manage the views ? as buttons and other ui content used for iphone will not be used in ipad or vice versa

Comment: It really just depends on how different. Note that there's nothing stopping you from using multiple storyboards, the API allows you to programmatically load view controllers from an arbitrary storyboard pretty easily